# Trying to make a dojo widget that will create a form

Tags: javascript, dojo

I wanted to make it so where I place the data-dojo-type="js/widget/SAUploadForm" for the upload widget it will generate a form there. Not sure what I wrong right now as no form is generated on the page.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Upload</title>
<script>
    dojoConfig = {
        async : true,
        parseOnLoad : false
    }
</script>
<script src="js/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <h1 align="center">Upload</h1>
    <br />
    <div data-dojo-type="js/widget/SAUploadForm"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My widget file: SAUploadForm.js

```
define(["dojo/_base/declare", "dojo/dom-construct", "dojo/parser", "dijit/_WidgetBase", "dijit/_TemplatedMixin"],
    function(declare, domConstruct, parser, ready, _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin) {
        decalre("SAUploadForm", [_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin], {
            formString: '<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/webapp/upload">' +
            '<table>' + 
                '<tr>' + 
                    '<td>File:</td>' + 
                    '<td><input type="file" name="file" value="Browse" accept=".sub" /></td>' + 
                '</tr><tr>' + 
                    '<td colspan="2"><button type="submit">Upload</button></td>' + 
                '</tr>' + 
            '</table></form>',


            buildRendering: function() {
                this.domNode.innerHTML = formString;
            }
        });

        ready(function() {
            parser.parse();
        });
});
```

This is located at js/widget/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,
there is so many wrong thing here...

- there is a typo: `decalre` instead of `declare`
- you should use `templateString` and not your custom `formString`
- you have to require `js/widget/SAUploadForm` if you want the parser to know about it
- you declare `ready` but you don't require it
- the result of `declare` should be returned

something like this should work:
(note: the snippets cannot work because the code needs to put the widget into a separate file)

```js
//This goes into js/widget/SAUploadForm.js
define(["dojo/_base/declare", "dojo/dom-construct", "dijit/_WidgetBase", "dijit/_TemplatedMixin"],
    function(declare, domConstruct, _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin) {
       return declare("js/widget/SAUploadForm", [_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin], {
            templateString: '<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/webapp/upload">' +
            '<table>' + 
                '<tr>' + 
                    '<td>File:</td>' + 
                    '<td><input type="file" name="file" value="Browse" accept=".sub" /></td>' + 
                '</tr><tr>' + 
                    '<td colspan="2"><button type="submit">Upload</button></td>' + 
                '</tr>' + 
            '</table></form>'
        });
});

//this goes into the index.html file
require(["dojo/parser", "dojo/domReady!", "js/widget/SAUploadForm"], function(parser) { 
  parser.parse();
});
```

```html
<script>
    dojoConfig = {
        async : true,
        parseOnLoad : false
    }
</script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<div>
    <div data-dojo-type="js/widget/SAUploadForm"></div>
</div>
```